# How to take single array input from user?

Tags: java, arrays

In the following code i marked the line that doesn't work.
Can someone explain me why this doesn't work?

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArrayLength {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter the array : ");

            double[] userArray = myScanner.nextDouble();//This line doesn't work        
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444786/taking-user-input-array-in-java-using-scanner-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [taking user input array in java using scanner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444786/taking-user-input-array-in-java-using-scanner-class)

Comment: Dont use an array if you only want a single value. If you need an array, then write the appropriate logic for filling each element.

Comment: "why this doesn't work?" -- because `nextDouble()` returns a `double` (a number), not `double[]` (an array).

Comment: then how to take input without declaring the array value?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are trying to assign a double value to a variable defined as Array with members double. In other words, your variable should be defined as double if u want such a value to be saved there or you have to read several double values and add them into your array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define array index in `int`, then only get `double` input

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Decide array length
        System.out.print("Please enter the array : ");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        //Create a double array to store  values
        double userArray[] = new double[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter value " + (i + 1) + " : ");
            userArray[i] = scan.nextDouble(); // you can store input with double datatype now
        }

        //Now display one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Value are " + (i + 1) + " : ");
            System.out.print(userArray[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

If you **don't want** to take input as array

```
 double num= myScanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: You cannot initialize array length with a double, it has to be integer. Instead of the two lines you've added it should be like :

double[] userArray = {myScanner.nextDouble()};

This way, the array will be initialized with length of 1 and that 1 value will be taken from the user input ;)

Comment: I think OP want to know how to get `double` input within the array length

Comment: Now you do not store the entered value into the array which I think is the main goal here :/ Question is not defined properly so we can only guess if the answer fits or not...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to set a double array from a line-separated input. If so, you could use something like this:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the array : ");

String strScan = myScanner.nextLine();
String[] aScan = strScan.split(" ");

double[] userArray = new double[aScan.length];

int i = 0 ;
for (String str : aScan) {
    userArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(str);
    i++;            
}
```

Comment: In cases like this it's recommended to use the extended FOR loop syntax. 
for (int i = 0; i < aScan.length; i++) {...}
both the arrays are now accessible using i as index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the user input to be located on exactly one line and you are sure that all the values (separated by a whitespace) could be parsed as Double I do recommend using the following statement:

```
double[] userArray = Arrays.stream(myScanner.nextLine().split(" "))
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .toArray();
```

Read whole next line as string, split it by whitespace, and then do parse each value into double.

If you only need to read a single double value and you are required to store it into an array then you could simply use the Array Initializer like this:

```
double[] userArray = {myScanner.nextDouble()};
```

This way userArray will have 1 element in total and it's first and only value will be the user input.

Answer (score 0):

myScanner.nextDouble() will output a single double instead of an array of doubles. So you would need to set that double equal to a specific index in the array instead of trying to set the whole array equal to a single double. I would suggest utilizing a for loop if you want to accept multiple doubles into the array.

For Example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < userArray.length; x++)
{
   userArray[x] = myScanner.nextDouble(); // x in this scenario is a specific position in the array
}
```

Also if the user input is formatted with a space between each double (i.e. 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 etc) myScanner.nextDouble(); will take the first double then go through the for loop again and take the next double etc. This is useful because the user input can all be on one line so the user can input the entire array at once.